# How to get d3 to recognize push+shift as an add-new-object-to-end and remove-old-object-from-beginning, rather than as just a data change in place

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I am trying to use d3.js to animate a faceted wheel of incrementing numbers, where 3 facets are shown at a time, and each time a "tick" occurs, the top facet disappears, the middle facet goes up one, and a new bottom facet is added. I want the motion to appear smoothly, but it doesn't.

I can't seem to figure out how to use transitions here, and it looks like d3 just sees my array of size 3 with changing values. When really it should see the add and remove each time, but I don't know how to do that.

How can I fix this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(event) {
 var state = {
  tick: 0,
  n: 0,
  wheel: [],
  nfacet: 3
 };
 
 function update_state(state)
 {
  if (state.wheel.length >= state.nfacet)
   state.wheel.shift();
  state.wheel.push(++state.n);
 }
 for (var i = 0; i < state.nfacet; ++i)
  update_state(state);
 
 function prepare_view(state)
 {
  var width = 200;
  var height = 200;
  var svg = d3.select("#wheel-container").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);
  var wheel = svg.append('g')
   .attr('id','wheel')
   .attr('transform','translate(3,3)');
 }
 
 prepare_view();

  var L = 30;
 function facet_enter(facet, t)
 {
  facet.append('text')
     .attr('text-anchor','middle')
     .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
     .attr('class','facet-label')
     .attr('x',L/2)
     .attr('font-size', 20)
     .attr('y',L/2);
  facet.append('rect')
     .attr('x',0)
     .attr('y',0)
     .attr('width',L)
     .attr('height',L)
     .attr('stroke','blue')
     .attr('fill','none');
  facet
     .attr('transform',function(d,i) { return 'translate(0,'+(i*L)+')'; });
 }
 
 function facet_merge(facet, t)
 {
  facet.select('text')
     .text(function(d,i) { return d; });
  facet.transition(t)
     .attr('transform',function(d,i) { return 'translate(0,'+(i*L)+')'; });
 }
 
 function update_view(state)
 {
  var wheel = d3.select("#wheel");
  var facets = wheel.selectAll('g');
  var t = d3.transition().duration(300);
  facets
      .data(state.wheel)
      .enter()
        .append('g')
     .call(facet_enter, t)
   .merge(facets)
     .call(facet_merge, t)
  facets.exit().remove();
 }
 
 var tmr = d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
  var do_something = false;
  var ticksize = 1000;
  while (elapsed > state.tick + ticksize)
  {
   do_something = true;
   state.tick += ticksize;
  }
  if (do_something)
  {
   update_state(state);
   update_view(state);
  }
 }, 200);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='wheel-container' />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I should have used key functions to ensure reasonable object constancy. See https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/

Here is an implementation that works along the lines I was originally thinking of:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(event) {
 var state = {
  nexttick: 0,
  ticksize: 1000,
  n: 0,
  wheel: [],
  nfacet: 3,
  init: true
 };
 
 function update_state(state)
 {
  if (state.wheel.length >= state.nfacet)
   state.wheel.shift();
  state.wheel.push(++state.n);
 }
 for (var i = 0; i < state.nfacet-1; ++i)
  update_state(state);
 
 function prepare_view(state)
 {
  var width = 200;
  var height = 200;
  var svg = d3.select("#wheel-container").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);
  var wheel = svg.append('g')
   .attr('id','wheel')
   .attr('transform','translate(3,3)');
 }
 
 prepare_view();

  var L = 30;
  
    function report_change(label)
 {
  return function(sel) {
   // console.log(label);
   // sel.each(function(d,i) { console.log(d,i); });
  }
 }
 function facet_enter(facets, t)
 {
  var facet = facets.append('g');
  facet.append('text')
     .attr('text-anchor','middle')
     .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
     .attr('class','facet-label')
     .attr('x',L/2)
     .attr('font-size', 20)
     .attr('y',L/2)
     .text(function(d) { return d; });
  facet.append('rect')
     .attr('x',0)
     .attr('y',0)
     .attr('width',L)
     .attr('height',L)
     .attr('stroke','blue')
     .attr('fill','none');     
  facet
     .attr('transform',function(d,i) { return 'translate(0,'+state.nfacet*L+') scale(1,0) ';});
  facet_move(facet, state.init ? null : t);
 }
 
 function facet_move(facet, t)
 {   
  (t ? facet.transition(t) : facet)
     .attr('transform',function(d,i) { return 'translate(0,'+((d-state.n+2)*L)+')'; });
 }
 
 function facet_update(facets, t)
 {
  facet_move(facets, t);
 }
 
 function update_view(state)
 {
  var wheel = d3.select("#wheel");
  var facets = wheel.selectAll('g');
  var t = d3.transition().duration(300);
  var upd = facets
      .data(state.wheel, function(d,i) { return d; });
    
  upd.call(report_change("UPDATE"))
        .call(facet_update, t)
     .enter()
     .call(report_change("ENTER"))
     .call(facet_enter, t)
     .merge(facets)
     .call(report_change("MERGE"))
  upd
           .exit()
     .call(report_change("EXIT"))
     .transition(t)
     .attr('transform','scale(1,0)')
     .remove();
 }
 
 var tmr = d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
  var do_something = false;
  while (elapsed >= state.nexttick)
  {
   do_something = true;
   state.nexttick += state.ticksize;
  }
  if (do_something)
  {
   update_state(state);
   update_view(state);
   state.init = false;
  }
 }, 200);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='wheel-container' />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is that as long as the position is dependent on the index, and the indices don't change (0,1,2 for example) then there is no transition in position, just a change of text based on the data.

I found another way (circular buffer essentially) which works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(event) {
var state = {
 tick: 0,
 n: -2,
 wheel: [],
 nfacet: 5,
 rotate: 0
};

function update_state(state)
{
 state.wheel[state.rotate] = ++state.n;
 state.rotate = (state.rotate+1) % (state.nfacet+2);
}
for (var i = 0; i < state.nfacet+2; ++i)
 update_state(state);

function prepare_view(state)
{
 var width = 200;
 var height = 200;
 var svg = d3.select("#wheel-container").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
 var wheel = svg.append('g')
  .attr('id','wheel')
  .attr('transform','translate(3,3)');
}

prepare_view();

var L = 30;
function facet_enter(facet, t, state)
{
 facet.append('text')
    .attr('text-anchor','middle')
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
    .attr('class','facet-label')
    .attr('x',L/2)
    .attr('font-size', 20)
    .attr('y',L/2);
 facet.append('rect')
    .attr('x',0)
    .attr('y',0)
    .attr('width',L)
    .attr('height',L)
    .attr('stroke','blue')
    .attr('fill','none');
 facet_merge(facet, t, state, true);
}

function facet_merge(facet, t, state, init)
{
 facet.select('text')
    .text(function(d,i) { return d; });
 function translator(d,i)
 {
  var ny = (i-state.rotate+state.nfacet+2) % (state.nfacet+2);
  var k = ny - (state.nfacet/2 + 1);
  var q = 0.5;
  var a1 = (Math.sin(k/state.nfacet*Math.PI*q) + 0.5)/3/q;
  var a2 = (Math.sin((k+1)/state.nfacet*Math.PI*q) + 0.5)/3/q;
  var sy = ((ny == 0 || ny == state.nfacet+1) ? 0 : (a2-a1))*state.nfacet;
  var ty = (((ny == 0 ? a2 : a1))*state.nfacet + 1) * L;
  return 'translate(0,'+ty+') scale(1,'+sy+')';
 }
 (init ? facet : facet.transition(t))
    .attr('transform', translator);
}

function update_view(state)
{
 var wheel = d3.select("#wheel");
 var facets = wheel.selectAll('g');
 var t = d3.transition().duration(300);
 facets
      .data(state.wheel)
     .enter()
       .append('g')
    .call(facet_enter, t, state)
  .merge(facets)
    .call(facet_merge, t, state)
 facets.exit().remove();
}

var tmr = d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
 var do_something = false;
 var ticksize = 1000;
 while (elapsed > state.tick + ticksize)
 {
  do_something = true;
  state.tick += ticksize;
 }
 if (do_something)
 {
  update_state(state);
  update_view(state);
 }
}, 200);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='wheel-container' />
</body>
</html>
```